# Magento: Checkout redirects to cart before 'Place Order' is pressed (should go to payal)

Tags: magento, checkout

this is my first actual post on StackOverflow. I'm on here quite often because you guys always solve my queries!

We have a problem in a checkout cart on a Magento site.

We have Magento version 1.4.1.1 and are using the one page checkout and Paypal Standard Checkout.

The problem appears when a customer adds lots of different products to their cart (say 7 or more). When they click on the 'Place Order' button, they should be taken to paypal to complete the order. But instead they are redirected to the cart (the default failure URL)

The checkout works fine when you buy a few items or many of the same item. It doesn't work when you buy multiple different items.

Any help/advice/solution/anything! would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Heather

Comment: Have you tried enabling "debug" mode within the admin for Paypal and looking over log files under /var/ for any insight? Posting this info up may help with a proper answer.  You may also want to look into upgrading to 1.4.2.

Comment: Can you have a look at the exception.log file in var/log/ and post the corresponding error message here?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, there are no recent errors reported in exception.log I don't think there is an error with the PHP installation either. The checkout works fine on the other magento sites on our server and I don't want to risk them breaking too :-\

Answer (score 4):

I to expereinced this issue... We run PHP Version 5.2.10, Magento ver. 1.3.2.4 and use Paypal Website Standard PRO...

We have been optimising the server install APC and tuning MySQL... Uninstalling / reinstalling APC to swap out a version of APC that use spin locks...

After completing these works and running an end to end test the Paypal integration failed to work... Or more to the point on clicking "Place Order" we were redirected to the cart page...

I reviewed the headers sent after pressing "Place order" and found that a 500 error was issued by the server and as Magento is a production configuration this error is not shown and the browser is redirected to the referrer, in this case the basket page...

Our PHP errors are logged to our Apache error_log and on view this I found the following entries:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/user/htdocs/lib/Zend/Feed/Abstract.php on line 101

I reviewed this further and discovered DOMDocument and found a post stating that the "PHP-XML Module" is required...

As we had been installing / installing software we ran "yum install php-xml"...

This resolved the issue!!! This is odd as this did work so implying this would not be the issue...

Answer (score 1):

A few more options / areas to look at...

I have experencied busy Magento installs with lots of products and orders, taking an extended amount of time to redirect to Paypal on clicking "Place Order". This is probably your actual problem and upgrading is the way forward, try upgrading to 1.4.2.0 (final 1.4 stable release)... but normally in this circumstance the process would complete after an extended wait (60sec long and more!!!)...

The fact that your checkout redirects to the cart page when you have many items may well be a timeout issue. Magento redirects back to cart from checkout submit when an error occures in the transfer to payment gateway page, so the page timing out or PHP running out of memory would result in you being redirected back to cart...

You should check:-

Apache: "Timeout" normally set at around 120 (secs) consider increasing
PHP: "max_execution_time" 18000 (secs) - Magento friendly figure

Also try increasing PHP setting "memory_limit" in the .htaccess file... setup 64, 128, 256 really increasing past 256 should not be an required.

Also start logging yopur PHP errors: log_errors On

Hope this helps

P.s. My original solution is clearly not correct as your failure only happens when you have multiple products in your cart...